# How to use ternary operator linq where clause

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Table : Id, Name,Subject,Score

```
1   Pinky    English   60
2   Pinky    Maths     40
3   Mahesh   Maths     50
4   Rani     Maths     50
5   Rani     Eco       50
```

I want to fetch record from table ,when Subject is maths, need record whose score should be more than 50,for remaining subject no condition.

Output :

```
1   Pinky   English   60
3   Mahesh  Maths     50
4   Rani    Maths     50
5   Rani    Eco       50
```

I tried like this :

```
var r = dbContext.Table1
                 .Where(x => x.Subject == "Maths" && 
                             x.Score >= 50 || 
                             x.Subject != "Maths");
```

It is working sometime but before above clause, there are few more filter as well base on role,subject get removed

How to write condition using ternary operator , when subject is Maths, then only fetch the record whose score is greater than or equal to 50.

```
(from tbl in dbContext.Table1 
 where tbl.Subject =='Maths' ? tbl.Subject =='Maths'
    && tbl.Score >= 50 : false  select tbl)
```

Is this

Comment: linq content is the same as a function -- why not just use if statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably just seeing the effects of operator precendence - `||` has higher precendence than `&&`, so you need to put parentheses around the `&&` clause:

```
var r = dbContext.Table1
                 .Where(x => (x.Subject == "Maths" && x.Score >= 50) || 
                             x.Subject != "Maths");
```

which is logically equivalent to:

```
var r = dbContext.Table1
                 .Where(x => x.Score >= 50 || x.Subject != "Maths");
```

or, using a ternary operator:

```
var r = dbContext.Table1
                 .Where(x => (x.Subject == "Maths") ? x.Score >= 50 : true);
```

Use whichever one you think will make more sense if you were to look at it again a week later...

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas in Linq are just like functions -- you can just use if statements and make it easy to read.

```
var r = dbContext.Table1
                 .Where(x => 
                        {
                          if (x.Subject == "Maths")
                          {
                            if (x.Score >= 50)
                               return true;
                            else
                               return false;
                           }
                           return false;
                        });
```